# Wcf service implementing Json and https only

Tags: c#, json, wcf, ssl, https

I am implementing a WCF service that needs to work with Json objects. This is working so far. Now, i want the service to accept https only, so no http.

For both requirements i have found a couple of samples that i have tested and that seem to work. However i am unable to get both requirements integrated into one config file.

This is my configuration for the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="SMApi.SApi">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" contract="SMApi.ISApi" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <!-- / -->
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <!-- / -->
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <!-- / -->
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <!-- / -->
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Try setting the security mode to transport on the `webHttpBinding`.  You'll need to add a binding configuration section to your config for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a binding configuration for `<webHttpBinding>` and setting the Security mode to transport.   You'll need to explicitly set the binding configuration to your endpoint.

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding name="SMApiWebhttpBinding">
    <security mode="Transport" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Then in your endpoint reference the above binding configuration via the `binding Configuration` attribute:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" 
         name="SMApi.SApi">
  <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" 
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="SMApiWebHttpBinding"
            contract="SMApi.ISApi" />
```